# Disk read error occured in dual boot ubuntu and windows 7

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I have GRUB2 with Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows 7. I recently get the error "Disk read error occurred". I am able to access the Windows partition from Ubuntu and I tried running `update-grub` and got this:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-17-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-17-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

But why is it, that I am not able to boot into windows? Is there any way by which I can rectify this without re-installing windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had to install Grub on to Ubuntu partition:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda1 --force
```

Then I repaired the MBR with windows recovery CD.

After that I booted to windows and installed EasyBCD (do not forget to install NeoGrub from the app).

And now I have a functional double boot machine with Windows 7 and Ubuntu on the same disk.

Comment: Linux Mint? Why Linux Mint?